# Converting float to timestamp in Postgresql using Peewee

Tags: postgresql, orm, peewee, datetime-conversion

I've got a hard time converting float column value into timestamp in Postgress. Actually, in SQL it looks like this:

```
TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + "t1"."timestamp" * INTERVAL '1 second') at time zone 'UTC'
```

Could you help me to express the same with the Peewee ORM?

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(t1.timestamp);
```

It looks like this would work... In peewee:

```
SomeModel.select(fn.to_timestamp(SomeModel.timestamp))
```